# trouble with jQuery ajax post not submitting data to asp page

Tags: jquery, ajax, cookies, greasemonkey

I have a Greasemonkey script that submits a form via an ajax request (post) with all the required name/value pairs. I get a response to the request but it does not contain any response to the data posted to the page. For instance the server should respond with some data like price, weight, etc.. but it's as if it didn't see the name values pairs in the ajax request.

I am looking at the ajax post parameters in Firebug for the Ajax call and they are the exactly the same the post parameters in a normal page submit. This site requires you to log in with a username/pw but once logged in I guess it keeps state with cookies. Can the reason why the Ajax call does work is because its not sending a particular cookie to the server in the Ajax request? Looking at the cookies sent with the ajax request its the same as the ones send with a normal page submit. Only one is listed as HttpOnly. Not sure if that makes a difference.

I never had this issue in the past and am at a loss to understand why I can't get this to work.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          test
// @description   test
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// @include       *http://extranet.alliancels.net/ordering/ebusiness/Pricing.aspx*
// ==/UserScript==

    jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://extranet.alliancels.net/ordering/ebusiness/Pricing.aspx',
    data: '__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__SCROLLPOSITIONX=0&__SCROLLPOSITIONY=0&__VIEWSTATE='+encodeURIComponent(jQuery('#__VIEWSTATE').val())+'&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtQuantity=1&ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPartNumber=70367301P&ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit=Submit',
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        }
    });
```

I realize there is nothing in the success callback, I am just looking at the response in firebug.

Edit: I tried this and it still does not return the "normal" response

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          test
// @description   test
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js
// @include       *http://extranet.alliancels.net/ordering/ebusiness/Pricing.aspx*
// ==/UserScript==


jQuery('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPartNumber').val('70367301P');
var form_data = $('#aspnetForm').serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://extranet.alliancels.net/ordering/ebusiness/Pricing.aspx',
    data: form_data,
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is this request being made to the same domain it originates from?

Comment: yes, as you can see in the @include it is he same URL as the ajax call.

Comment: Is it possible that the page sends more than 1 post to the server?  That is, it uses *state* checking? ... Also, we really can't tell much more from the question.  Post the form HTML and any relevant JS.

Answer (score 0):

your data must be in key, value pairs like this:

```
data: { 'keyname' : 'value' }
```

in your code:

```
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://extranet.alliancels.net/ordering/ebusiness/Pricing.aspx',
    data: { 'data' : '__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__SCROLLPOSITIONX=0&__SCROLLPOSITIONY=0&__VIEWSTATE='+encodeURIComponent(jQuery('#__VIEWSTATE').val())+'&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtQuantity=1&ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtPartNumber=70367301P&ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnSubmit=Submit'}
    type: 'POST',
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data){
        }
    });
```

you are posting only the value. provide a key that you can use it to retrieve in server side:

```
string posteddata= Request.Form["keyname"];
```

Comment: That is not correct, that shows just one keyname "data" and everything else as the value.

Comment: yes it does, the problem is that the way you send data is in correct. I was just giving an example. if you want to send more data you should make more key:value pairs. like: {'key1': 'value1' , 'key2' : 'value2' , 'key3' : 'value3' }

Comment: Well with all due respect I copied your code exactly and it posted exactly how I stated above, data as the keyname and the rest as the value. Then could you kindly explain why I am seeing this result in FB?

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with ASP MVC a lot recently and sometimes when I want the data as a FormCollection I will wrap up the input fields in Ajax.BeginForm tag that looks similar to this

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ActionName", "Controller", null, new AjaxOptions
            { }, new { id ="AjaxForm" }))
```

I believe when it is rendered out it looks like this:

```
<form action="ActionName"  data-ajax="true" data-ajax-url="/Controller/ActionName" id='AjaxForm'> </form>
```

This will allow the form to actually post the FormCollection like a 'normal' POST...You may have to review the syntax a little I am not on my development laptop to give you the exact code but its more or less like the above.